# Spring data MongoDB full text search with DBRef

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, full-text-search, spring-data-mongodb

I tried to make full text search using spring data mongodb and i got a problem. I have 3 documents which has relation with @DBRef:

```
@Data
@Document
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Order {
   @DBRef
   private Client client;
   @DBRef
   private Company company;
   private long time;
   @TextIndexed
   private String type;
   ...
}

@Data
@Document
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Client {
    @TextIndexed
    private String name;
    @TextIndexed
    private String lastName;
    ...
}

@Data
@Document
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Company {
  @TextIndexed
  private String name;
  private String type;
  ...
}
```

so I have OrderRepository in which I want to implement query criteria but it doesn't work as I want. I mean I make query in OrderRepository and it checks only all @TextIndexed in which order only. I want that it searchs not only Order but in related Documents as well. If in short, I want to search only orders and related documents as well from OrderRepository. Is it possible at all? By Default @DBRef doesn't allow it and I don't want to create for each document search query. Example, I have a order in which client name is James. When I make query just by name "James" it should search all orders where client name is James. How to achieve that? Thnks

Answer (score 1):

There are many restrictions on DBREF usage from MongoDB, a better way is to use manual references so take a look at RelMongo framework if you are using Spring Data MongoDB